# "require: array or java.lang object, found: MyArrayList" error

Tags: java

Here is my lab which I am doing
[image: Lab]

And the code which I write is

```
package lab.pkg01;
import java.util.*;
public class Lab01 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] L1 = {"Abu Dhabi", "Dubai", "Sharjah", "Ajman"};
        String[] L2 = {"Fujara", "Dubai", "Ras Alkhaima", "AlAin"};
        
        MyArrayList list1 = new MyArrayList(L1); 
        MyArrayList list2 = new MyArrayList(L2);   
    }  
}

class MyArrayList{
    static ArrayList<String> MyList = new ArrayList<>();  
    MyArrayList(String[] list){
        for(String i:list){
            MyList.add(i);
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean contains(String e){
        boolean b = false;
        ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<MyList.size(); i++){
            if(e == MyList.get(i)){
                positions.add(i);
                b = true;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
    
    public boolean addAll(MyArrayList e){
        for(String s: e){
            if(MyList.contains(s)){
                MyList.add(s);
            } else {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public boolean removeAll(MyArrayList e){
        for(String s: e){
            if(!MyList.contains(s)){
                MyList.remove(s);
            } else {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String s = "";
        for (String i : MyList){
            s = s+" "+i;
        }
        return "List: "+s;
    }
}
```

It is giving an error

> found: MyArrayList but reuired: array or java.lang object

on addAll() and removeAll() method. Can anyone help me out in resolving this.

Actually What I want to do is to compare Object created in main method to the MyList array so that I can perform addAll() and removeAll() methods.

Comment: First of all you `String` comparison is not good on `e == MyList.get(i)`. Strings should be compared with `equals()`. And a `static` will be used for the entire life time of the program execution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't be using static for no reason. I don't think you need static for `myList` and the `contains()` method in this case.([What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)). Be very careful when using and dealing with static.

Also, Your issue is the for loop. Your Strings are stored in `ArrayList myList`, from the `MyArrayList` class. Plus `if(MyList.contains(s))` in your `addAll()` method should be `if(!MyList.contains(s))` , because you don't want to add duplicates (I'm assuming it's just your typo.

So instead of for example:

```
    public boolean addAll(MyArrayList e){
        for(String s: e){
            if(!MyList.contains(s)){
                MyList.add(s);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You should access your string through myList like so:

```
    public boolean addAll(MyArrayList e){
        for(String s: e.myList){
            if(!MyList.contains(s)){
                MyList.add(s);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Also, as Aman says you should use `equals()` to compare Strings.
Additionally, your `removeAll()` and `addAll()` only returns true, so you may want to fix that as well!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I used to remove static from the list, then it gives error in MyList.get(i)

Answer (score 1):

1. It is better that you don't use `static` list. Or you have to clear it for every object creation, which is ugly. So, change that first to non `static` variable.
2. `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()` instead of `ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()`.
3. In your `#contains()` method compare `String` with `equals()` instead of `==`.
4. `AddAll` does not seem to work since String is not `MyArrayList` in `for(String s: e)` of `#addAll()` and `#removeAll()`.

```
    public boolean addAll(String[] e){
       boolean isChanged = false;
        for(String s: e){
            if(!myList.contains(s)) {
                myList.add(s);
                isChanged = true;
            }
        }
        return isChanged;
    }
```

5. Some modifications on `removeAll`.

```
    public boolean removeAll(String[] e){
        boolean isChanged = false;
        for(String s: e){
            if(myList.contains(s)) {
                myList.remove(s);
                isChanged  = true;
            }
        }
        return isChanged ;
    }
```

6. Lastly, try to use Java bean naming style. e.g. `ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>()`, **myList** not **MyList**.